# Override CSS code in Wordpress

Tags: css, overriding

I'm creating a wordpress site using various plugins. The main one is WP Super Edit to allow the production of tables, however I've hidden the table lines by inserting:

```
td {
    border-style: hidden;
    padding: 5px .5em 5px .4em;
}
```

due to an issue with firefox. In some cases I would like to display lines for various tables.

Is there a code I can add prior to the table in the "Text" box to override the one inserted above.

Comment: Have you tried using the `!important` to override it when you have to?

Answer (score 0):

The `!important` directive in css means that it should override all other rules of give type. If there is another `!important` directive first, it will be overriden by the last one.

```
.ignore_td{
   border-style:<some_other_value>!important;
   padding:<some_ther_value>!important;
}

<td class="ignore_td" />
```

or

```
table.ignore_td td{
   border-style:<some_other_value>!important;
   padding:<some_ther_value>!important;
}

<table class="ignore_td" />
```

Comment: This makes sense but I'm struggling to figure where in the TEXT I should paste <td class="ignore_td" />

Comment: Not sure, what do you mean by `TEXT` a page code? plugin code? You mean in wordpress editor? Try using raw html code, you can edit this way too.

Comment: Yes I'm using the wordpress editor...I've added the !important directive to the Custom CSS with my parameters  but unsure where to paste <td class="ignore_td" /> into the html code using the WP editor.